# Panel data with R

Tags: r, rscript, panel-data

We are using the `plm` package for panel data models.
We try to run the model but we get the warning message Duplicate couples.

We run the following scrit:

```
minidb$id <- minidb %>% group_indices(client, product)
pdata.frame(minidb, index=c("id","date"))
```

And we obtained the following warning mesage:

```
Warning message:
In pdata.frame(minidb, index = c("id", "date")) :
  duplicate couples (id-time) in resulting pdata.frame
 to find out which, use e.g. table(index(your_pdataframe), useNA = "ifany")
```

Then we run the model:

```
plm(formula=amount~age+membership, data=minidb, index=c("id","date"), model="within", effect="twoways")
```

And we ontained the following Error message:

```
Error in xj[i] : invalid subscript type 'list'
In addition: Warning message:
In pdata.frame(data, index) :
  duplicate couples (id-time) in resulting pdata.frame
 to find out which, use e.g. table(index(your_pdataframe), useNA = "ifany")
```

We know this is not a mistake in our data, since the structure of our data is the following one: each line has 3 unique identifiers: client, date and product.

How can we create an id with 3 dimensions, date, and then combine client and product to avoid the error duplicate couples

[image: data base]

Comment: Could you please add a sample of your data rather than a screenshot, for instance copy-pasting the result of `dput(minidb)` within your question ?

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce the warning statement with a similar dataframe. Have you tried the suggestion of the warning statement : `table(index(pdata.frame(...)), useNA = "ifany")` ?